# Database Update Status " Needs Upgrade" Sp2013

Tags: 2013, upgrade, content-database, service-pack

I am in the process of upgrading sp2013 farm to SP1 upgrade soon. To prep for that i was going though datbase status page in central admin and saw the following:

[image]

With that info on hand i was curious enough to know what objects needed upgrade in the farm. So i ran `stsadm.exe -o localupgradestatus`

That got me results about all the objects in my farm. Within those objects identified 3 objects either needed upgrade or cannot be upgrades:

```
<object>
<name>sp_SecureStore_PR13</name>
<type>Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceDatabase</type>
<level>2</level>
<status>Cannot Upgrade</status>
```

```
<object>
<name>sp_StateService_PR13</name>
<type>Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.StateDatabase</type>
<level>2</level>
<status>Cannot Upgrade</status>
```

```
<object>
<name>MTS</name>
<type>Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb</type>
<level>7</level>
<status>Needs Upgrade</status>
```

How should i go about fixing these objects, looks like SecureStore service db and StateService db cannot be upgraded, what does that exactly mean. How is that going to effect my SP1 upgrade. The last object "MTS" of type Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPweb, i dont have such db in my farm so waht exactly is it pointing towards.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some thing in your content database required updates. couple of possibilities:

- you may restore the site collection in that db
- upgrade from last time not completed successfully.
- may be you moved the content/ pages from different version which required upgrade.

**Solution**

- run upgrade-spcontentdatabase "DB name" and once it completed successfully you will see no action required.

I would prefer to run this before applying the SP1. But in my experience i applied the CU in same situation and that works.

Comment: Thank you for the information , but in databasestatus.aspx page it says its departments_PR13_03 is the one that needs to get upgraded but in localupgradestatus reports says it is MTS. Which one should i upgrade.  Also the issue here is in my DEV and QA env i dont see that issue it is happening only in prod.  We host heavy volume of sites in that departments db, therefore i was getting nervous.

Comment: As I said couple of things cause this....but if you are nervous then don't run upgrade command. ...When you apply sp1, it will update it once you finish configuration wizard